# How to split a Pandas DataFrameGroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I can split a dataframe into chunks using the following:

```
def split_df_into_num_chunks(cls, df, chunks = 10): 
    list_of_df = list()
    initial_len = len(df.index)
    chunk_size = initial_len // chunks
    for i in range(chunks):
        list_of_df.append(df[i*chunk_size:(i+1)*chunk_size])
    if (i+1)*chunk_size < initial_len:
        list_of_df.append(df[(i+1)*chunk_size:initial_len])
    return list_of_df
```

However I cant work out how to split a DataFrameGroupBy eg

```
    id        date                            qty
0  540689582 2017-09-22 00:00:00+00:00        41
1  540689582 2017-09-23 00:00:00+00:00        44
2  540689582 2017-09-24 00:00:00+00:00        52
3  540689583 2017-09-22 00:00:00+00:00        56
4  540689583 2017-09-23 00:00:00+00:00        31
```

where I want to split the DataFrameGroupBy into n roughly equal sized sub- DataFrameGroupBys, and I want to preserve the groups of id's (ie keep each group intact, split between groups when splitting)

Any clues?

Comment: whats the end game here? why are you splitting the df into chunks after groupby?

Comment: Im running a celery job and want to process each chunk sequentially so that I can update user as to progress